# How do you interpret the feedbacks of my boss

Tags: postdocs, career-path, early-career, feedback

I have a PhD in biological sciences but working (for two years by now) as a data analyst (I can say something like a bioinformatician) in a university analysing cancer omics

My boss says that I am an excellent bioinformatician but I must learn how to structure my data when presenting or even before any analysis

He says I would not get any credit unless I learn this

Every morning we have online lab meeting, when seeing my colleagues presentation I feel too bad about myself

I see how they are deep and accurate in their statement

But me only see frigid feedbacks, even PhD students in our lab don't take me serious never ask me to help them in their data

I feel too isolated.. I am getting to the end of my career but everyday I feel the current position would be my last job opportunity in my life

How would you approach such an annoying situation in your academic life?

Thank you for any word

Comment: @Buffy Why assume the very worst? It seems that OP needs to learn how to present data in a way that is useful to her "customers". At least that's what I read into it. What data to analyse, what to show, in which form, etc. For instance, some people present just all data they have, flat (I am not saying this is the case here, just as example), without highlighting what it means, what the consequences are, what recommendations to make etc. OP should explain better what she recognises in her colleague's presentations to be better than in hers. Presentation skills are learnable.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, I make no assumptions, but it is a euphemism. It was a question only.

Comment: It sounds like you might be experiencing depression.  You should seek help from a licensed mental health professional.

Comment: Sorry @CaptainEmacs, by euphemism, you says that my boss is unsatisfied with my work and just expresses that in an indirect way?

Comment: @Angel I do not know, as there are not enough details in your question but, yes, this may be. Have they explained at some point in more detail what they expect?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs no just saying my plots are not self explanatory ... but I can say frustration on my boss's face when facing me. The worst Phd student in our lab never asks help from me. Once my boss told I have imposter syndrome

Comment: @Angel I think identifying precisely why they are dissatisfied is essential here. We cannot guess, you will have to tell us. You did a PhD, so you know how to write a thesis. So, what's missing?

Comment: You right @CaptainEmacs because of my weird educational system (I have been studied in my country) which is 100% different with the way people here obtain PhD (I see how a PhD student in our lab progress which is earth to sky differs with where I have obtained my PhD).

Answer (score 4):

There are certain conventions on how to structure thoughts, write texts, present information, and give talks. Find out and learn them. A first step is to ask your supervisor for specific advise, so you can improve these skills.

For example, is is common to finish sentences with a period and to group sentences together to form paragraphs. Note that practically everybody does this. It is a convention to efficiently convey ideas by giving the reader some expected structure she can hold on to. If you don't do this, this already sticks out as part of a "bad presentation". So, learn what conventions exist and use them.

This may help to address presentation and writing part:

http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/R2/re-writing.pdf

http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ellenber/mntcg/TalkTipSheet.pdf

PS: This should have been a comment rather than an answer as it only addresses one aspect. I don't have enough reputation to comment.